# how can i get a column of multilevel index after pivot_table in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': [1,1,2,2,3,4,4],
    'id': [1,1,1,2,2,2,3],
    'item': [200,201,200,333,334,334,444],
    'buy': [1,1,2,5,4,0,1]
})

df = df[['date','id','item','buy']]


date    id  item    buy
0   1   1   200     1
1   1   1   201     1
2   2   1   200     2
3   2   2   333     5
4   3   2   334     4
5   4   2   334     0
6   4   3   444     1
```

method1:

> df2 = df.pivot_table(index=['id','item'], columns=['date'],
>   aggfunc='sum', fill_value=0).reset_index()

```
    id  item    buy
date            1   2   3   4
0   1   200     1   2   0   0
1   1   201     1   0   0   0
2   2   333     0   5   0   0
3   2   334     0   0   4   0
4   3   444     0   0   0   1
```

how can i get a column '1' or '2' or '3' or '4' of 'buy' column?

my trial is rename name of columns like this.

```
df2.columns = ["".join((str(i),str(j))) for i,j in df2.columns]

    id  item    buy1    buy2    buy3    buy4
0   1   200     1       2       0       0
1   1   201     1       0       0       0
2   2   333     0       5       0       0
3   2   334     0       0       4       0
4   3   444     0       0       0       1
```

and df2['buy1'], df2.buy2... that what i want

here is my question.

how can i get a column of multilevel index after pivot_table in pandas? directly on multilevel structure without rename...

---

method 2:

> df2 =
>   df.groupby(['id','item','date']).buy.sum().unstack(fill_value=0).reset_index()
>   df2.columns.names=['']

```
    id  item    1   2   3   4
0   1   200     1   2   0   0
1   1   201     1   0   0   0
2   2   333     0   5   0   0
3   2   334     0   0   4   0
4   3   444     0   0   0   1
```

if using groupby & unstack like method 2, i can avoid multilevel index problem, though

but i still wanna know a method get a column of multilevel index after pivot_table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `pivot` , you can point out `values`, then you will received what you need

```
df.pivot_table(index=['id','item'], columns=['date'], values='buy',aggfunc='sum', fill_value=0).reset_index()
Out[64]: 
date  id  item  1  2  3  4
0      1   200  1  2  0  0
1      1   201  1  0  0  0
2      2   333  0  5  0  0
3      2   334  0  0  4  0
4      3   444  0  0  0  1
```

Comment: wow. easiest way.
In another case, mutilevel dataframe at first, how can i do it?

Comment: @J.Doe yep, :-) happy coding man(PS: if this is what you need, Can you accept it )